# Cross Domain iFrame - http to https

Tags: php, iframe, cross-browser, cross-domain

I've got a little bit of a problem that I'm trying to get around.

I have domain A: http://example.com and I need to add an iFrame to this site pointing to domain B: https://example2.com...

I've tried this but it just shows a blank page and doesn't load anything.

Is there anyway around this? I'm thinking off adding a page on domain A that has a 301 redirect to the page on domain B... Would this work?

Any suggestions would be great.

Thanks.